# Toggle functions for drop down for a clock time widget

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, datetime, jquery-ui

I'm fairly new to JQuery/JavaScript and I'm trying to refactor the following code:

```
$('#hour').click(function() {
  $('#clockHours').slideToggle();
  $('#clockMinutes').hide();
});

$('#minutes').click(function() {
  $('#clockMinutes').slideToggle();
  $('#clockHours').hide();
});

//print clicked onto views
$('.timeSelect').click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $('#hourView').val( text );
});

$('.minuteSelect').click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $('#minuteView').val( text );
});
```

I haven't had much luck figuring out how to improve the code. Here is a [CodePen of the current working code](http://codepen.io/Lgalan90/pen/wKdVwq) and here's [what I have tried](http://codepen.io/Lgalan90/pen/yYprXV).

Comment: What do you dislike about the current code?  Because given that you are using jquery, and given the scope of this problem, your solution seems clear and readable.

Comment: There is no much code to refactor. I would suggest to avoid duplicated selectors storing them into variables.

Comment: My goal was to refactor the code in a way that would allow me to,for example, add an extra button with the same functions without having to write a new, separate function. I will continue to work on it and possibly bump the topic once I can start to make sense of my requirements and code.

Comment: The JS in the CodePen is more extensive than the code in the question. Do you have a reason for that? What exactly do you want us to review?

Comment: The JS in the current working code CodePen includes extra functions for other parts of the clock. What I am trying to do is create a function that will allow the hour and minutes drop down to work (including any other buttons I may add in the future) through one function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a few simple things you could do to help clean up this code.  The first thing I always recommend is to create a closure for your script using an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).  This allows your code to run in its own scope and keeps everything [out of the global scope](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). You can also pass in `jQuery` to the function expression and safely refer to it as `$`.

```
(function($, undefined ) {
  // pass in undefined for very old (ES3) browsers
  // code goes here
})( jQuery );
```

The next thing you should consider is [caching your selections](http://jsperf.com/why-cache-jquery-selectors).  Since accessing the DOM is one of jQuerys slowest operations, you want to minimize this as much as possible. Anything you refer to more than once, you should cache.

```
var $min = $('#clockMinutes');
var $hr = $('#clockHours');
```

I prefix all of my jQuery selections with $ so I know they are jQuery objects.

You should also start using `on` for defining your events instead of the shorthand of `click`.  Behind the scenes, `click` uses `on` so just skip the middle man.

```
$min.on('click', function() {
  //code here
});
```

You might also want to consider [DRYing](http://rmurphey.com/blog/2010/07/12/patterns-for-dry-er-javascript/) your code.  Since the click functions on both the `clockMinutes` and `clockHours` are so similar, you can combine them and just pass in the "main" element you want to work on.  For example:

```
function updateScreen( $el ) {
  $el.slideToggle();
  if ( $el === $hour ) { 
    $min.hide();
  } else {
    $hour.hide();}
  }
}
```

Here is an updated code sample based on the above.  *Note*: I call an `init` function on `document.ready` to kick off the functionality.

```
(function( $, undefined ) {
  //place holder variables for our selections
  var $min, $hour, $minView, $hrView;

  function init() {
    $min = $('#clockMinutes');
    $hour = $('#clockHours');
    $minView = $('#clockMinutes');
    $hrView = $('#minuteView');
    $('#hour').on('click', function() { updateScreen($hour); });
    $(' #minutes').on('click', function() { updateScreen($min); });
    $('.timeSelect').on('click', function() { updateView($hrView); });
    $('.minuteSelect').on('click', function() {updateView($minView);});
  }

  function updateView( $view ) {
    $view.val( $(this).text() );
  }

  function updateScreen( $el ) {
    $el.slideToggle();
    if ( $el === $hour ) { 
      $min.hide();
    } else {
      $hour.hide();
    }
  }

  $(function() {
    init();
  });

})(  jQuery );
```

Hope you find this helpful. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I've read the articles and found caching hint very helpful for me. Thanks for your informative answer Gary! I'll be working on making sense of the way your answer works and try to learn from it.